# Can one Create Auto Orders using PayPal payments api - where tokenised payments are initiated from website not using paypal repeat purchases?

Tags: php, paypal

We currently have a website that uses eWay token payments and setup Auto Order for customers. They can manage what items are in the auto orders and at what frequency the orders will be placed.
After the first order we can save the users 'Token' with eWay and charge their card at each instance.

We would like to add in the ability to pay with PayPal, but cannot see a similar feature where future orders can be placed without the user interacting.

The issue is that the price may differ from original payment, as discounts for the item may change or the user could add in other products to the auto order. So we don't want to have a repeat purchase setup in PayPal, rather automatically charge the users account when needed.

Been looking through paypal API docs and nothing is jumping out as the correct way to proceed.

We have tried payments through eWay to PayPal however they are not supporting paypal through their gateway anymore so are not much help.

Our website is PHP, Mysql driven and we currently use PayPalExpress checkout API for single orders.

Answer (score 0):

For PayPal, the receiving account needs a feature called "reference transactions". This is not enabled by default in the live environment (though it is in sandbox). It requires business approval, so the PayPal account owner should contact PayPal's general customer support or an account manager (note: not technical support) to discuss the business need for the feature.

Once approved for the "reference transactions" feature on a live business account, PayPal can guide you on which API to best integrate to make use of this. Something like v2 or [v3 vault](https://developer.paypal.com/beta/vault/) and that API's payment tokens are a possibility that sounds exactly what you are describing, though there are other (older/legacy) APIs that use something called a "billing agreement" as what's effectively a token as well.